# Prove that if $(G,\#)$ is a finite group and subset $A$, $|A|>|G|/2$ then any element of $G$ can be written as a combination of two elements of $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Prove that if $(G,\#)$ is a finite group and subset $A$, $|A| > |G|/2$ then any element of $G$ can be written as a combination of two elements of $A$.

Note that $A$ is not necessarily a subgroup.
If $|G|=n$ then $|A| > ⌊n/2⌋$.
I know that at least (for $|A| = ⌊n/2⌋+1$) $A$'s gonna have the identity element or an element with its inverse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $g\in G$. Consider the set $gA^{-1}$. The cardinality of this set is same as cardinality of $A$.

Now $$\begin{align}
| A\cap gA^{-1} |&\geq  |A| +|gA^{-1}|- |G| \\
&>0. 
\end{align}$$

So $\exists \ a,b \in A$ such that $ a=gb^{-1} \implies ab=g.$